# Calendar: get date components, weird case

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, foundation

I'm trying to find out why this piece of code works so strange. You can find details below:

```
let nowDate = Date()
let threeDayBeforeNowDate_t1 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60 * 60 * 24 * 3)
let oneDayAfterNowDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1)
let threeDayBeforeNowDate_t2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60 * 60 * 24 * 3)
let threeDayBeforeNowDate = nowDate.addingTimeInterval(-60 * 60 * 24 * 3)

let diff_1 = threeDayBeforeNowDate_t1.timeIntervalSince(nowDate) - threeDayBeforeNowDate.timeIntervalSince(nowDate) // about 0.009357
let diff_2 = threeDayBeforeNowDate_t2.timeIntervalSince(nowDate) - threeDayBeforeNowDate.timeIntervalSince(nowDate) // about 0.010063
let diff_3 = threeDayBeforeNowDate_t2.timeIntervalSince(nowDate) - threeDayBeforeNowDate_t1.timeIntervalSince(nowDate) // about 0.000416

let calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.dateComponents(Set([Calendar.Component.day]), from: threeDayBeforeNowDate, to: oneDayAfterNowDate) // result = "day: 4 isLeapMonth: false"
calendar.dateComponents(Set([Calendar.Component.day]), from: threeDayBeforeNowDate_t1, to: oneDayAfterNowDate) // day: 4 isLeapMonth: false
calendar.dateComponents(Set([Calendar.Component.day]), from: threeDayBeforeNowDate_t2, to: oneDayAfterNowDate) // day: 3 isLeapMonth: false
```

I don't understand, why I get so different results while dates (threeDayBeforeNow...) differ by less than a second.

Comment: **Never** use `60 * 60 * 24` as the duration of a day. Think of daylight saving time transitions, a day can have 23, 24, or 25 hours. Use the proper calendar methods.

Comment: Martin, I see, it was just for test.

Comment: *"I get so different results while dates differ by less than a second"* – In the last case the dates differ by (a tiny bit) **less** than 4 full days, therefore the result is 3. If you print all date components then you'll see it more clearly.

Comment: I have printed components. So, a get: https://imgur.com/a/bibMZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dávid already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222656/1187415), the problem is that the various dates
are computed at different points in time, therefore the difference is not
exactly 4 days. In particular, the difference between
`threeDayBeforeNowDate_t2` and  `oneDayAfterNowDate` is *less* than
4 days, and that's why the `.day` component of the difference is `3`.

Here is a simplified example demonstrating the problem (in a Playground):

```
let nowDate = Date()
let date1 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60 * 60 * 24 * 4)
let date2 = nowDate.addingTimeInterval(-60 * 60 * 24 * 4)

let calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: date1, to: nowDate)
// day: 3 hour: 23 minute: 59 second: 59 nanosecond: 994143066 isLeapMonth: false

calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: date2, to: nowDate)
// day: 4 hour: 0 minute: 0 second: 0 nanosecond: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

`date2` and `nowDate` differ by exactly 4 days, but `date1` and `nowDate` 
differ by a tiny be *less than* 4 days (assuming that there is no
daylight savings transition in this timespan).

Comment: @G.Veronika: The difference between threeDayBeforeNowDate_t1 and oneDayAfterNowDate is *greater* than 4 days.

Comment: Ok, I see. It was a bug in the code. Thanks! I thought it was
'let oneDayAfterNowDate = nowDate.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 1)', but now I see... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that some time passes between creating `nowDate` and your other variables, where you use the `Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:)`initializer.

Both `Date()` and `Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:)` use the system time to get the current time when the execution reaches that particular variable. Regardless how small, there will always be some small delay between the different calls to the system time and hence even if you create two `Date` objects using `Date()` in two consecutive lines of code, they won't represent the exact same point in time.

Running in a Playground, the following piece of code shows this behaviour:

```
let now1 = Date()
let now2 = Date()
now1.timeIntervalSince(now2) //-0.0002049803733825684
```

If you want consistent `Date` objects, create a single variable, in which you store the date of creation, using `Date()` as you do at the moment for `nowDate`, then use that same variable for creating your other `Date` objects using `nowDate.addingTimeInterval()` as you currently do for `threeDayBeforeNowDate`.

Comment: I know about this, but in the case the dates do not differ significantly, so I expect to get day differences the same.

Comment: Well, this is an edge case, but that small difference is exactly what makes the daycomponents return a different result for the two. And as @MartinR suggested in comments, don't use manual calculation of the dates using `timeIntervalSince` for calculating dates. Use the proper Calendar methods.

Comment: If it was an edge case, would it be repeated in an hour?